# Define sort options of Kendo Grid in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to create a Kendo Grid in Angular.  I originally had something like this:

```
<div kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-data-source="myArray"></div>
```

In my scope, myArray is an array that gets dynamically assigned.  gridOptions was defined as something like this:

```
gridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        sort: { field: "number", dir: "asc" }
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "number", title: "Number" }
    ],
    sortable: true
};
```

But the problem here is that the default sort is ignored, presumably because Kendo is using the k-data-source instead and totally ignoring this in the options.  However, if I try removing k-data-source, and modifying my gridOptions to this:

```
gridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        data: myArray,
        sort: { field: "number", dir: "asc" }
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "number", title: "Number" }
    ],
    sortable: true
};
```

Then I can see that the grid is sorted, but when myArray gets assigned, the grid does not populate with the data (I just end up with an empty grid).
What's the best way to achieve a default sorted grid using Kendo Angular directives?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the dataSource part of the options:

```
dataSource: {
    data: new kendo.data.ObservableArray(myArray),
    sort: { field: "number", dir: "asc" }
}
```